# Image map only works in Google Chrome

Tags: css, imagemap

I'm currently trying to get this image-map to work:

```
<img src="products1.png" usemap="products1-map" style="margin-bottom: 36px" />

<map id="products1-map" name="products1-map">

    <!-- Some comment -->

    <area shape="rect" coords="234,261,315,281" href="#" alt="Test">
    <area shape="rect" coords="218,282,314,318" href="#" alt="Test">

    <area shape="rect" coords="441,243,537,279" href="#" alt="Test">
    <area shape="rect" coords="416,278,512,314" href="#" alt="Test">

    <!-- Some comment -->

    <area shape="rect" coords="229,463,325,499" href="#" alt="Test">
    <area shape="rect" coords="218,500,314,536" href="#" alt="Test">

    <area shape="rect" coords="425,461,521,497" href="#" alt="Test">
    <area shape="rect" coords="416,497,512,533" href="#" alt="Test">

    <area shape="rect" coords="622,463,718,499" href="#" alt="Test">
    <area shape="rect" coords="615,495,711,531" href="#" alt="Test">

    <!-- Some comment -->

    <area shape="rect" coords="230,686,326,722" href="#" alt="Test">
    <area shape="rect" coords="216,722,312,758" href="#" alt="Test">

</map>

<img src="some-image1.png" style="float: right"/>

<img src="some-image2.png" style="margin-bottom: 16px"/>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome, but not in IE or FF.

How would you troubleshoot a problem like this?

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, i found your issue, you miss `#` about `usemap` name , here:

```
<img src="img/da.png" usemap="#products1-map" style="margin-bottom: 36px" />
```

I hope now everything working :)